# User selects "All", nothing passed to filter

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm creating a shiny app which includes a drop down list. The user has a couple of options. These then are used in a filter as shown below.

```
filteredData <- reactive({

data %>% 
  filter(Month >= input$months[1],
         Month <= input$months[2],
         Location.ID == input$loc,
         )
})
```

I want to add "All" in the drop down associated with input$loc and then want nothing to be passed to the filter.

I'm not really sure what I need to pass to the filter so it doesn't do anything. I tried NULL but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you try combining it with a checkboxInput labelled "All"  and filtering if not checked?

Comment: No. I don't think have a checkbox and a list is a great solution for the user.

Comment: You could use a if statement and not filter is All is selected.

Comment: Yeah that's where I was going but i'm having some trouble writing the statement within the code above.

Comment: Try `input$loc=="All" | Location.ID == input$loc` as the last condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate in two `filter` functions.

```
filteredData <- reactive({
    DF <- data %>% 
      filter(Month >= input$months[1],
            Month <= input$months[2])
    if(input$loc == "All") {
       DF 
    } else {
       DF %>% filter(Location.ID == input$loc)
    }
})
```

Comment: Looking at other peoples Shiny apps, it seems like this is the way to go. Thanks